# MySQL BETWEEN DATE RANGE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario where I need to pull up delivery dates based on a table below (Example)

```
job_id | delivery_date
1      | 2013-01-12
2      | 2013-01-25
3      | 2013-02-15
```

What I'm trying to do is show the user all the delivery dates that start with the earliest (in this case it would be 2013-01-12) and add an another 21 days to that. Basically, the output I would expect it to show of course, the earliest date being the starting date 2013-01-12 and 2013-01-25. The dates past the February date are of no importance since they're not in my 21 date range. If it were a 5 day range, for example, then of course 2013-01-25 would not be included and only the earliest date would appear.

Here is main SQL clause I have which only shows jobs starting this year forward:

```
SELECT date, delivery_date 
FROM `job_sheet` 
WHERE print_status IS NULL 
    AND job_sheet.date>'2013-01-01'
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with 1 SQL query, or must I go with a mix of PHP as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select *
from job_sheet
where print_status IS NULL
  and delivery_date >= (select min(delivery_date)
                        from job_sheet)
  and delivery_date <= (select date_add(min(delivery_date), interval 21 day)
                        from job_sheet)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86ef1/2)

If you are worried about the dates not being correct, if you use a query then it might be best to pass in the start date to your query, then add 21 days to get the end date. Similar to this:

```
set @a='2013-01-01';

select *
from job_sheet
where delivery_date >= @a
  and delivery_date <= date_add(@a, interval 21 day)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86ef1/12)

Comment: I see how this would work. My only concern is that how would you show only the jobs created starting as of the new year? For some reason on my side, when I add `AND delivery_date>='2013-01-01'` nothing shows up...

Comment: If you have delivery dates before 2013-01-01, then the expression `min(delivery_date)` isn't going to do the Right Thing. Use a literal date instead.

Comment: @DimitriTopaloglou I agree with Catcall, if you are unsure of the date range, then you should use literal strings as the value for the ranges. So pass into your query the startdate and then add 21 day to that value for the end date. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date,
       delivery_date
FROM job_sheet
WHERE print_status IS NULL
AND job_sheet.date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM job_sheet) AND
                           (SELECT MIN(date) FROM job_sheet) + INTERVAL 21 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT j.job_id
     , j.delivery_date
  FROM `job_sheet` j
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(d.delivery_date) AS earliest_date
           FROM `job_sheet` d
          WHERE d.delivery_date >= '2013-01-01'
       ) e
    ON j.delivery_date >= e.earliest_date
   AND j.delivery_date < DATE_ADD(e.earliest_date, INTERVAL 22 DAY)
   AND j.print_status IS NULL
 ORDER BY j.delivery_date
```

---

(The original query has a predicate on `job_sheet.date`; the query above references the `d.delivery_date`... change that if it is supposed to be referencing the `date` column instaed.)

If the intent is to only show `delivery_date` values from today forward, then change the literal `'2013-01-01'` to an expression that returns the current date, e.g. `DATE(NOW())`